# nginx http redirect wrongfully doubles the parameters (via AWS ELB)

Tags: nginx, ssl, amazon-web-services, redirect, docker

For example, when I browse

`http://example.com/foo?x=1&y=2`

nginx redirects me to

`https://example.com/foo?x=1&y=2?x=1&y=2`

Now if I continue to redirect, I get

`https://example.com/foo?x=1&y=2?x=1&y=2?x=1&y=2?x=1&y=2`

It keeps doubling the parameters, not sure what did I do wrong.

My nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name {{ .SERVER_NAME }} www.{{ .SERVER_NAME }};

  ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx.key;

  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$server_name$REQUEST_URI permanent;
  }

  # Nginx will reject anything not matching /
  location / {
    # Reject requests with unsupported HTTP method
    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|POST|HEAD|OPTIONS|PUT|DELETE|PATCH)$) {
      return 405;
    }

    # Only requests matching the whitelist expectations will
    # get sent to the application server
    proxy_pass http://site_container:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host                 $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Port     $http_x_forwarded_port;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

This is an ECS architecture with both nginx and app containers on the same EC2 instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `rewrite` directive appends the query string to the replacement URL by default, in a manner similar to Apache's `[QSA]`. From the [documentation](https://nginx.org/r/rewrite):

> If a replacement string includes the new request arguments, the previous request arguments are appended after them. If this is undesired, putting a question mark at the end of a replacement string avoids having them appended, for example:
>
> ```
> rewrite ^/users/(.*)$ /show?user=$1? last;
> ```

**But, that's *not* how you should fix the problem.**

This has a further problem, in that the http to https redirect is inefficient. This `if` has to be evaluated on *every* request, and the `rewrite` has a gratuitous regex. See [Taxing Rewrites](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites) for more information.

Instead, you should have a completely separate `server` block for HTTP versus HTTPS, and remove the `if`/`rewrite` from the HTTPS `server` block entirely.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80; # You also forgot this...

  server_name {{ .SERVER_NAME }} www.{{ .SERVER_NAME }};

  return 301 https://{{ .SERVER_NAME }}$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works great with the question mark. As for the separate server block, I'm using AWS ELB as the HTTPS front end and traffic is routed to the server on HTTP (also for healthcheck). So a separate block would put the ELB in unhealthy state.

Comment: @Casper I suppose so. But you really should read the rest of the answer too.